# How can I assign an unspecified generic function to a variable in TypeScript?

Tags: generics, typescript

How can I assign an unparameterized generic function to a variable?

In the following example consider my attempt to create the `areArraysShallowlyEqual` function by making a composition of generic functions and assigning the result of the composition to a variable:

```
export function areNullablesEqualOver<a>(areEqual: (one: a, another: a) => boolean)
:(one: a, another: a) => boolean {
    return function(one, another) {
        if (one == null) {
            if (another == null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (another == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return areEqual(one, another);
            }
        }
    };
};

export function areArraysEqualOver<a>(areEqual: (one: a, another: a) => boolean)
: (one: a[], another: a[]) => boolean {
    return function (ones, anothers) {
        var length = ones.length;
        if (length !== anothers.length) return false;
        for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            if (areEqual(ones[index], anothers[index])) continue;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

export function areSame<a>(one: a, another: a): boolean {
    return one === another;
}

// PROBLEM:
export var areArraysShallowlyEqual<a> = areNullablesEqualOver<a>(areArraysEqualOver(areSame));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using a generic class. This isn't exactly the same as what you are doing as you would need to instantiate the class with the type argument, rather than passing a type argument to the individual functions - but given that you cannot pass a type argument to a variable your suggested implementation isn't possible.

The interfaces are not required, you could repeat the type annotation throughout instead, but they help distinguish between the array and non-array variations.

The `areArraysEqualOver` and `areNullablesEqualOver` have been swapped in the `areArraysShallowlyEqual` property - this is because the `areArraysEqualOver` method doesn't return a type compatible with the other signatures because it returns an array comparer and all the other methods accept a non-array comparer.

```
interface EqualityFunction<T> {
    (one: T, another: T) : boolean;
}

interface ArrayEqualityFunction<T> {
    (one: T[], another: T[]) : boolean;
}

class Example<a> {
    areNullablesEqualOver(areEqual: EqualityFunction<a>) : EqualityFunction<a> {
        return function(one, another) {
            if (one == null) {
                if (another == null) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (another == null) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return areEqual(one, another);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    areArraysEqualOver(areEqual: EqualityFunction<a>) : ArrayEqualityFunction<a> {
        return function (ones, anothers) {
            var length = ones.length;
            if (length !== anothers.length) return false;
            for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                if (areEqual(ones[index], anothers[index])) continue;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    areSame(one: a, another: a): boolean {
        return one === another;
    }

    areArraysShallowlyEqual = this.areArraysEqualOver(this.areNullablesEqualOver(this.areSame));
}
```

The calling code looks like this:

```
 var example = new Example<string>();

 example.areArraysShallowlyEqual(['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']); // true

 example.areArraysShallowlyEqual(['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']); // false
```